# Vim script execute command skips every second substitute

Tags: vim

I am cutting my teeth on functions to learn more about scripting. Why does the script replace only every second word found?
I'm aware that there are better ways to replace the word under the cursor, such as `nnoremap <F6> :%s/<C-r><C-w>/`, but the question remains. 
I tried to use the substitute() function but that didn't work at all.

```
function! FReplace(rep)
    let f = expand("<cword>")
    echo "Find:" f "      Replace with:" a:rep
    execute "%s/"f"/"a:rep"/g"
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 Replace call FReplace(<f-args>)
```

A line in a dummy text changes only from

```
xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx
```

to

```
yyy xxx yyy xxx yyy xxx yyy xxx
```

but they should all be `yyy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `:help :execute`:

> Multiple arguments are concatenated, with a space in
>   between.  To avoid the extra space use the "."
>   operator to concatenate strings into one argument.

That means, if `f` is `'xxx'` and `a:rep` is `'yyy'`,

```
execute "%s/"f"/"a:rep"/g"
```

is equivalent to

```
execute "%s/ xxx / yyy /g"
```

which just runs

```
%s/ xxx / yyy /g
```

Here (marked with `^`) are all matches on a line of sample data:

```
xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx
   ^^^^^   ^^^^^   ^^^^^
```

Every second word is not matched because the spaces are part of the match and matches cannot overlap.

The fix is to give `:execute` a single string without extra spaces:

```
execute "%s/" . f . "/" . a:rep . "/g"
```